# parseInt a SQL count(*)

Tags: java, sql-server

I have the following function and I am trying to compare the number of students enrolled in a class with the class max.  If the number enrolled is greater than the class max, I want to return a message that says, "The Class if Full".

I am trying to convert the SQL statements to numbers and compare that way, but am getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException on the line:

int currentNumberInClassAsInt

the selectedClass variable is a user-entered number for the class they want to enroll in.

```
public static void classFullCheck() {
    try {
        String currentNumberInClassAsString = ("SELECT class_id, COUNT(*) FROM ClassSelector.student_x_class WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery(currentNumberInClassAsString);
        int currentNumberInClassAsInt;
        if(rs.next()){
            currentNumberInClassAsInt = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        String classSizeAsString = ("SELECT class_size FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
        rs = myStmt.executeQuery(classSizeAsString);
        int classSizeAsInt;
        if(rs.next()){
            classSizeAsInt = rs.getInt("class_size");
        }
            if (currentNumberInClassAsInt > classSizeAsInt){
                System.out.println("Sorry, this class is Full!");
        }
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL) {
        SQL.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My SQL Table layout is:

students

student_id | student_name | hometown

classes

class_id | class_name | Description class_size

student_x_class

student_id | student_name | class_id | class_name

Let me know if I left out any essential info.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: As of now you are trying to parse the String containing the statement.

Comment: This code appears to be vulnerable to sql injection. You should use parameterized queries instead of building up a string to execute.

Comment: @SeanLange, thanks, thats a good point, I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the data using your `ResultSet`

```
int currentNumberInClassAsInt = rs.getInt("count"); // Getting the value of column "count"
```

OR

```
int currentNumberInClassAsInt = rs.getInt(2); // Getting the value of second column
```

---

The best way is to check first if `rs.next()` returns `true`, otherwise you'll get an exception

---

```
int currentNumberInClassAsInt;
if (rs.next()) {
    currentNumberInClassAsInt = rs.getInt(2);
}
```

Comment: so what would I eliminate in my current code?  would I not need to use executeQuery?  Why 2?

Comment: @J.Doe executeQuery returns a `ResultSet`. You'll need it to retrieve the objects from your database.

Comment: so what variable would I put as "count"?

Comment: I appreciate the help and patience.  Don't I want that value in the rs.getInt(__) to be the returned number in class value from my SQL table?

Comment: @J.DOE Excuse me I did not understand the question

Comment: I'm just confused on what goes into the "count" location

Comment: I have updated my code; if you could take a look I'd appreciate it!